# Bootstrap Container & Container Fluid have an issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7. 
I have used  and  to add content to the page.

When I use container-fluid, it will not span the content across the page but will limit the size to the page center area.

The same thing happened when I used container. It spans to the outside of the page> My screen resolution is 1366 x 768.

*This is the code I have used*

```
    <div class="container">

      <h4>Bootstrap Buttons</h4>

      <!-- The Large size buttons -->
      <p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Default</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Primary</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Success</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Info</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Warning</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Danger</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-lg">Link</button>
      </p>

      <!-- The default size buttons -->
      <p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>
      </p>

      <!-- The small size buttons -->
      <p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Default</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Primary</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Success</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Info</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Warning</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Danger</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm">Link</button>
      </p>

      <!-- The small size buttons -->
      <p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Default</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Primary</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Success</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Info</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Warning</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Danger</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">Link</button>
      </p>  

    <!-- Bootstrap container & container-fluid -->
    <!-- Bootstrap container example -->
    <div class="container bootcontainer">
      <h1>Hello, world! - Using Container</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap container-fluid example -->
    <div class="container-fluid bootcontainerfluid">
      <h1>Hello, world! - Using Container Fluid</h1>

    </div>
```

Comment: your container-fluid is inside of a container

Comment: There is a lot of problems with your HTML. Simplify the code to a minimal example. `container-fluid` is full width in Bootstrap. You most likely have wrong markup or custom CSS that is overriding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the **container** that contains the other ones, so:

```
   <!--Bootstrap Modal (Dialog Box / Pop-up Window) Example-->
      <div class="container-fluid">
       ...
```

Then replace **container** with **container-fluid** everywhere you need it, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Actually it's an HTML break. I hadn't put the `<div>` tag after declaring the 'Bootstrap Button Example'.

Thanks anyway!

Regards,
Chiranthaka